# Query Syntax for Execute SQL Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I need to generate excel report with data for different areas such that each area's data is under a different tab in the same excel file. This report is to be overwritten with fresh records each month. Hence, I referred to the link mentioned below:

http://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/

As I need to overwrite all the tabs of the Excel destination, I entered following commands in the 'Drop Excel Table' and 'Create Excel Table' Execute SQL tasks.

```
DROP TABLE `Excel Destination1`;
DROP TABLE `Excel Destination2`;

CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination1`(
`column1` VarChar(50),
`column2` VarChar(15),
`column3` VarChar(25),
`column4` DateTime
);
CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination2`;
`column1` VarChar(50),
`column2` VarChar(15),
`column3` VarChar(25),
`column4` DateTime
);
```

But, as I execute the Package, I am getting error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DROP TABLE `Excel Destination1`;DROP TABLE `Excel Destination2..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error in DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

What's wrong with my syntax in the Execute SQL Tasks?

Comment: You're way overcoding this. Just have a blank Excel workbook containing all of your tabs sitting in a folder. Delete/Archive the "previous" workbook from last week, using a File System Task. Copy new (blank) workbook with another File System Task. Boom, done.

Comment: To answer the question though, you possibly need a terminator between the statements.

Comment: @JacobH, I have a semicolon at the end of each DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statement. Isn't that the terminator?

Comment: Not according to your error message: `DROP TABLE \`Excel Destination1\` DROP TABLE \`Excel Destination2\``

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Just edited my question with the correct error message. It is the same error even with the semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the syntax as shown below, worked for me.

```
DROP TABLE `Excel Destination1`
Go
DROP TABLE `Excel Destination2`
Go

CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination1`(
`column1` VarChar(50),
`column2` VarChar(15),
`column3` VarChar(25),
`column4` DateTime
)
Go

CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination2`
`column1` VarChar(50),
`column2` VarChar(15),
`column3` VarChar(25),
`column4` DateTime
)
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with code in an SQL Task component, SSIS didn't like the semi-colons. I took them out and the code ran.